# Apache2 WebDAV writable directory in readonly server

Tags: apache2, webdav

To serve files, I set up a readonly WebDAV with Apache2 serving from `davs://dav.example.com/`.  However, I want a subdirectory (`davs://dav.example.com/uploads/`) that is writable by the logged in user.

To make my site readonly, I used the following:

```
  ...

<Directory /var/www/dav>
    Options +Indexes

    DAV On

    Order allow,deny
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Not for public access!  Login only"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd

    <Limit GET OPTIONS PROPFIND>
        Require valid-user
        Deny from all
    </Limit>

    <Limit PUT POST DELETE PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
        Require host dav.example.com
        Deny from all
    </Limit>

    Satisfy Any
</Directory>

  ...
```

I've tried making `<Directory /var/www/dav/upload>`, copying the `<Limit PUT`... with `Require valid-user` in it, but that didn't work.  When creating a file in the `/upload/` dir, the server responded with a `500` error.

Is this possible? I have access to the `site.conf` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a `<Directory /var/www/dav/upload>` block with this in it:

```
<LimitExcept GET OPTIONS PROPFIND PUT POST DELETE PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
    Require valid-user
    Deny from all
</LimitExcept>
```

This also works in `.htaccess` files, if needed.